# How to change PHP code, by javascript code or jquery code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I replace a PHP echo with a javascript or jquery, of this html code?

My intention is to use a jquery or javascript function to insert a variable name in an html code. And in this way have a multiple form that I can submit with different data.

My HTML:

```
<form id = "display" method="post" name="form_teste<?php echo $idteste;?>" action="detalhe_imovel.php">
<input hidden="hidden" name="idteste" value="<?php echo $idteste;?>">
</form>
<div id  class="box--tete-item" onclick="document.form_teste<?php echo $idteste;?>.submit();">
```

My jquery:

```
 $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data)
        {
          if(data.sucesso == "true" )
          {
            var i;
            var newid;
            for(i=id_val;i<data.numero;i++){
                //Change the id in the form
                newid = "display_" + data.out[i].id;
                $('#display').attr('id', newid);  
                //change the name of the form???    
                //change the id in the onclick in the div???    
             }
          }
          else
          {
           ...
         }
       }               
});
```

I'm trying something like this to change the id of the form, but I'm not sure that this will works?

My code to change the id of form:

```
 newid = "display_" + data.out[i].id;
 $('#display').attr('id', newid);
```

Please some help needed. Thank you for the future help.

Comment: you can't change PHP code with JS, by the time you want to do anything with javascript, PHP code has already been intepreted and is no longer on the .html or .php file. You can however just plain change any element's ID with JS or jQuery.

Comment: _"but I'm not sure that this will works?"_ - Well, you could always try it?

Comment: Why do you want or think you need to jump through all these complicated hoops?

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you put an answer, so I can close the question. I'm asking you, becouse you were the one who clarified me best in this matter.

Comment: Naa, go ahead and pick one of the answers that best helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Forms in HTML don't have a "name" attribute (you can use it, but it will do nothing for you). Using the "id" attribute also won't help you when submitting data to your server.

It seems that you're trying to dynamically build a list of forms based on information received via AJAX. Probably to display a grid of products (houses, in your case) that you can add to cart, or something like that. If that assumption is correct, read on:

Assuming you're using jQuery or ZeptoJS (`$.ajax`), you could first create a template for your form:

```html
<form id="my-form-template" style="display:hidden" action="submit.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<div id="form-target-area">
</div>
```

(note that there's no PHP code here - not needed)

And then in JS, something like this:

```
var $formTargetArea = $('#form-target-area'),
    $formTemplate = $('#my-form-template');

$.ajax({complete: function(data, status){
    // .. check data integrity
    $formTargetArea.empty(); // remove old forms from previous requests
    for(var i=id_val;i<data.numero;i++){
        var $newForm = $formTemplate.clone()
          .appendTo($formTargetArea)
          .show();
        $newForm.children('input[name=item_id]').first()
              .attr('value', i);
    }
}});
```

(note: did not test the code - adjustments may be needed)

Similar results can be achieved in a much simpler and elegant manner by using libraries such as Angular, React, Ember, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Chrome console to see if the id has changed。Here I use the javascript to try, and maybe you can debug to see.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:;" id="aid">点击修改id</a>
<input type="text">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    a.onclick = function () {
        if(input.value!=''){
            a.id = input.value + '_aid';
            console.log(document.getElementById(input.value + '_aid'));//Output the result, indicating that id has changed
            console.log(document.getElementById("aid"));//null
        }else{
            console.log("no");  
        }
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```